# Как удалить определеный файл через button

Tags: c#

У меня проблема появилось, мне нужно постоянно один файл удалять чтобы зайти, и я хочу через Button сделать так чтобы при нажатии этой кнопки удалялся тот самый ненужный файл, как это сделать ?[image: во]

Comment: Повесьте команду `os.system('del /q название_файла')` на нажатие кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Можно также воспользоваться методами из пространства имен `System.IO`. Если известна директория `dirName`, где файл расположен, и имя файла `fileName`, то в обработчик нажатия кнопки можно добавить такой код:

```
        var pathToFile = Path.Combine(dirName, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(pathToFile))
            File.Delete(Path.Combine(dirName, fileName));
```